# How to use css global variables in scss file?

Tags: css, sass

I am gonna use css global variables in scss file so that I can change the button colour in any time.

I want to do like this:

```
:root {
--button-color: #FF0000;
}

$button-color: var(--button-color);

...
```

But this makes the issue now.

Comment: you cannot use CSS variables in SASS, use SASS variables with CSS

Comment: *But this makes the issue now.* Huh?

Answer (score 0):

SASS variables are compile time and final value depends on all files were `@import` in line. CSS variables are run-time and are calculated based on cascade(say if any parent element redeclares variable - it will be applied to children).

Also take a look into docs section on [difference between](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables)

You can use [`css-vars`](https://github.com/malyw/css-vars) to compile SASS variables into CSS custom properties. But you still cannot use CSS custom properties in SASS code, say, to calculate some value - since CSS property is not initialized yet.

Even with `css-vars` plugins, things are rather messy, because SASS files does not describe how component tree looks like finally so we cannot see cascade.

TL;DR; don't mix SASS variables and CSS custom properties. Use first for compile-time variables/calculation only and use latest one for run-time/cascade-based styling. Probably prefer using CSS custom properties only.